# In NetBeans IDE disable popup error description on hover?

Tags: netbeans

In NetBeans IDE how to disable popup error description on mouse hover?

Example:

[image]

*P.S. I'm using NetBeans  17.*

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. At a granular level you can turn individual hints on or off using **Tools > Options > Editor > Language > etc...**. But it seems that you just want to prevent any messages at all being displayed when the mouse overs over any error in any language. Is that correct? Can you update your question to provide a specific example of a _"popup error description"_ you want to suppress?

Comment: I provided an example screenshot. Thank you very much for trying to help.